# Track purchases made through WooCommerce Tiered Pricing Table plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I use [WooCommerce Tiered Pricing Table plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/tiered-pricing-table-for-woocommerce/) and I want to be able to see which one of them purchased by this plugin in admin panel (details of order information).
I have modify this code but not working and only show No.
Please check it and help me.

Any help is appreciated.

```
/*Track purchases made through WooCommerce Tiered Pricing Table plugin.*/
function track_purchases_from_tiered_pricing_table($order_id) {
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    // Loop through the order items
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        // Get the product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Check if the Tiered Pricing Table plugin file is being loaded
        if (class_exists('Tier_Pricing_Table')) {
            // Update the order meta to indicate the purchase from the plugin
            update_post_meta($order_id, '_purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table', 'yes');
            break; // Exit the loop if a product from the plugin is found
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'track_purchases_from_tiered_pricing_table');

 //Display the purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin information in the admin panel
function display_purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table_info($order) {
    // Get the order ID
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    
    // Get the purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin meta value
    $purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table = get_post_meta($order_id, '_purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table', true);
    
    if ($purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table === 'yes') {
        echo '<p><strong>Purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin: </strong>Yes</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p><strong>Purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin: </strong>No</p>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table_info');
```

Comment: Start by verifying whether _inserting_ that meta value actually worked as intended.

Comment: @CBroe I did it but couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, will add a custom field to the order if an item is tiered priced, and will display it in Admin order pages:

```php
// Track purchases made through WooCommerce Tiered Pricing Table plugin.
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'track_purchases_from_tiered_pricing_table', 10, 2 );
function track_purchases_from_tiered_pricing_table( $order, $data ) {
    $has_tiered_pricing = false; // Initializing
    
    // Loop through the cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        // Loop  through extra meta keys from the product
        foreach ( wp_list_pluck( $item['data']->get_meta_data(), 'key' ) as $key ) {
            // Check for a meta_key that has 'tiered_pric' substring
            if ( strpos($key, 'tiered_pric') !== false ) {
                $has_tiered_pricing = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If an tiered priced item is found, flag the order
        if ( $has_tiered_pricing ) {
            $order->update_meta_data( '_has_tiered_pricing', '1' );
            break;
        }
    }
}

 // Display the purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin information in the admin panel
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table_info');
function display_purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table_info($order) {
    // Display if the order has tiered priced items
    printf( '<p><strong>Purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin: </strong>%s</p>', 
         $order->get_meta( '_has_tiered_pricing' ) ? 'Yes' : 'No' 
    );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Addition:** Targeting discounted tiered price items only

If you only want to add this order metadata, for items that have "tiered prices calculated" (so a discounted tiered price), use instead the following:

```php
// Track purchases made through WooCommerce Tiered Pricing Table plugin.
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'track_purchases_from_tiered_pricing_table', 10, 2 );
function track_purchases_from_tiered_pricing_table( $order, $data ) {
    $has_tiered_pricing = false; // Initializing
    
    // Loop through the cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        // Loop  through extra meta key /value pairs from the product
        foreach ( wp_list_pluck( $item['data']->get_meta_data(), 'value', 'key' ) as $key => $value ) {
            // Check for 'tiered_pricing_cart_price_calculated' meta key  
            if ( $key === 'tiered_pricing_cart_price_calculated' && $value === 'yes' ) {
                $has_tiered_pricing = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If an tiered priced item is found, flag the order
        if ( $has_tiered_pricing ) {
            $order->update_meta_data( '_has_tiered_pricing', '1' );
            break;
        }
    }
}

 // Display the purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin information in the admin panel
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table_info');
function display_purchased_from_tiered_pricing_table_info($order) {
    // Display if the order has tiered priced items
    printf( '<p><strong>Purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin: </strong>%s</p>', 
         $order->get_meta( '_has_tiered_pricing' ) ? 'Yes' : 'No' 
    );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**Addition 2:**

How to see the cart items (product) protected extra metadata (key / value pairs).

This plugin generates extra metadata specifically for cart items (product).

The following code will display that extra protected metadata in the bottom of cart and checkout pages *(only for admins)*, so you will be able to use the correct keys / values that you need to make my code working *(accordingly to your product settings with this plugin)*:

```php
// Displaying cart items (product) extra protected metadata in the bottom of cart and checkout pages
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart', 'display_product_extra_metadata_for_admins'); // cart
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'display_product_extra_metadata_for_admins'); // checkout
function display_product_extra_metadata_for_admins() {
    if( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) return; // Only admins

    echo '<pre>';
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        echo '<p>Name: '.$item['data']->get_name() . ' | Quantity:' .  $item['quantity'] . '</p>';
        print_r( wp_list_pluck( $item['data']->get_meta_data(), 'value', 'key' ) ); 
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Once done, you can just remove it, or disable it.

Comment: I've tested. Not working and for products are purchased show `"Purchased from Tiered Pricing Table plugin: No"`
Also the text-domain that have mentioned by plugin developer is `tier-pricing-table`

Comment: @MohsenAmra Sorry, but I have this plugin, so my code is tested and works (if it is not tested, I put "It should work")… Even if it's not the right meta key in my code, you have the way to make it work finding the right convenient meta key by yourself.

Comment: So many thaks for your response. I've tasted again and It does not working for product are purchased based on the plugin.
https://s8.uupload.ir/files/screenshot_g4k.png

Comment: So many many thanks for your response Sir. I really appreciate it. I've tested your addition but in my site working inversely. So for purchased product by Tiered Pricing Table plugin shows No and for not purchased product by Tiered Pricing Table plugin show Yes.

Comment: Is it possible to use the second code along with the first code for discount conditions on the site?

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. Generally I want to track which one of my products purchased by the mentioned plugin. So based on your codes when I've tested it I've seen for purchased product show NO and for not purchased product show YES and completely working in my site inversely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254370/discussion-between-mohsen-amra-and-loictheaztec).

Comment: I gladly accepted your answer and thank you for your time.

Comment: I have added the code, at the end, that will allow you to see the related protected extra metadata that this plugin is generating on the cart items (product), visible on cart and checkout pages (only for admins). Then you will be able to use it in my code, to make it work for your related product settings.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to be on the right track. However, there are a few things we can check to troubleshoot the issue. Here are a few suggestions:

Make sure that you have correctly installed and activated the WooCommerce Tiered Pricing Table plugin.

Double-check that the class name 'Tier_Pricing_Table' is correct and matches the class used by the plugin. This is important for the condition class_exists('Tier_Pricing_Table') to work properly.

Ensure that the code snippet is placed within the active theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin file.

Verify that the WooCommerce hooks 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed' and 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address' are supported by your WooCommerce version.

If you have checked all of these aspects and the code is still not working as expected, please provide any error messages or specific details about the issue you are encountering. That information will be helpful in diagnosing the problem further.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.